# Trying to modify randomising javascript to cater for different screen widths

Tags: javascript

I've been able to modify a Javascript that will allow me to display a random selection of 6 out of 18 divs on a page in a random order at a screen width above 1284px and then just 4 at a screen width below 1285px:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".randomItem").hide();

  var elements = $(".randomItem");
  var elementCount = elements.size();

  if ($(window).width() < 1285) {
    var elementsToShow = 4;
  } else if ($(window).width() > 1284) {
    var elementsToShow = 6;
  }
  
  var alreadyChoosen = ",";
  var i = 0;
  
  while (i < elementsToShow) {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * elementCount);
    if (alreadyChoosen.indexOf("," + rand + ",") < 0) {
      alreadyChoosen += rand + ",";
      elements.eq(rand).show();
      ++i;
    }
  }
});
```

To enable this script to be fully responsive, I would like to add an addEventListener, but trying to do so just results in syntax errors.

I was wondering if somebody could advise me how to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: What event listener are you trying to add? What have you tried out so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a resize event listener to the window.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  var elementsToShow;
  if ($(window).width() < 1285) {
    elementsToShow = 4;
  } else if ($(window).width() > 1284) {
    elementsToShow = 6;
  }
  
  var alreadyChoosen = ",";
  var i = 0;
  elements.hide();//hide all
  while (i < elementsToShow) {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * elementCount);
    if (alreadyChoosen.indexOf("," + rand + ",") < 0) {
      alreadyChoosen += rand + ",";
      elements.eq(rand).show();
      ++i;
    }
  }
}).resize();//trigger resize on page load
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `$(window).resize` event but you need to take some considerations to avoid changing the random items while the browser is resized.

You should also use an array for the `alreadyChoosen` as it makes more sense and is easier to handle.

```js
var widthThreshold = 1285;

function selectRandomItems(elementsToShow) {
  $(".randomItem").hide();

  var elements = $(".randomItem");
  var elementCount = elements.size();

  var alreadyChoosen = [];
  var i = 0;

  while (i < elementsToShow) {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * elementCount);
    if (alreadyChoosen.indexOf(rand) < 0) {
      alreadyChoosen.push(rand);
      elements.eq(rand).show();
      ++i;
    }
  }
};

var overThreshold = null;
$(window).on('resize', function() {
  var width = $(window).width();
  var shouldRandomize = overThreshold === null ||
    (width < widthThreshold && overThreshold) ||
    (width >= widthThreshold && !overThreshold);

  if (shouldRandomize) {
    overThreshold = width >= widthThreshold;
    if (overThreshold) {
      selectRandomItems(6);
    } else {
      selectRandomItems(4)
    }
  }
}).trigger('resize');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="randomItem">1</div>
<div class="randomItem">2</div>
<div class="randomItem">3</div>
<div class="randomItem">4</div>
<div class="randomItem">5</div>
<div class="randomItem">6</div>
<div class="randomItem">7</div>
<div class="randomItem">8</div>
<div class="randomItem">9</div>
<div class="randomItem">10</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally extract things like taking random elements from an array (often called sampling). Into their own helper method, since that is something that's generally useful.

With the helper `sampleN` extracted you can solve your issue easily using:

```
elements.hide();
$(sampleN(elements, elementsToShow)).show();
```

Here `sampleN` accepts an [array-like or iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Description) collection (which is compatible with a jQuery collection) and returns a normal array with the sampled elements.

```js
// helpers
const randomInt = (limit) => Math.floor(Math.random() * limit);
const clamp = (n, min, max) => Math.min(Math.max(n, min), max);

function sampleN(arrayLike, n) {
  const items   = Array.from(arrayLike);
  const samples = [];
  
  // move n random items from `items` to `samples`
  for (n = clamp(n, 0, items.length); n > 0; --n) {
    const index  = randomInt(items.length);
    const [item] = items.splice(index, 1);
    samples.push(item);
  }
  
  return samples;
}

// solution
let elementsToShow;
const thresholds = [ // in decending order by width
  { width: 1285, elementsToShow: 6 },
  { width:    0, elementsToShow: 4 },
];

$(window).on('resize', function () {
  // find the matching threshold
  const windowWidth = $(window).width();
  const theshold    = thresholds.find(({width}) => windowWidth >= width);
  
  // prevent randomizing if threshold.elementsToShow is the same
  if (theshold.elementsToShow == elementsToShow) return;
  elementsToShow = theshold.elementsToShow;
  
  // find and update the elements
  const $elements = $(".randomItem");
  const $samples  = $(sampleN($elements, elementsToShow));
  
  $elements.hide();
  $samples.show();
}).trigger('resize');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="randomItem">1</div>
<div class="randomItem">2</div>
<div class="randomItem">3</div>
<div class="randomItem">4</div>
<div class="randomItem">5</div>
<div class="randomItem">6</div>
<div class="randomItem">7</div>
<div class="randomItem">8</div>
<div class="randomItem">9</div>
<div class="randomItem">10</div>
```

Or without ES5 features:

```js
// helpers
function randomInt(limit) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * limit);
}

function clamp(n, min, max) {
  return Math.min(Math.max(n, min), max);
}

function sampleN(array, n) {
  var items   = array.slice();
  var samples = [];
  
  for (n = clamp(n, 0, items.length); n > 0; n--) {
    var index = randomInt(items.length);
    var item  = items.splice(index, 1)[0];
    samples.push(item);
  }
  
  return samples;
}

function find(array, fn) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (fn(array[i], i, array)) return array[i];
  }
}

// solution
var elementsToShow;
var thresholds = [ // in decending order by width
  { width: 1285, elementsToShow: 6 },
  { width:    0, elementsToShow: 4 },
];

$(window).on('resize', function () {
  // find the matching threshold
  var windowWidth = $(window).width();
  var theshold    = find(thresholds, function (threshold) {
    return windowWidth >= threshold.width
  });
  
  // prevent randomizing if threshold.elementsToShow is the same
  if (theshold.elementsToShow == elementsToShow) return;
  elementsToShow = theshold.elementsToShow;
  
  // find and update the elements
  var $elements = $(".randomItem");
  var $samples  = $(sampleN($.makeArray($elements), elementsToShow));
  
  $elements.hide();
  $samples.show();
}).trigger('resize');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="randomItem">1</div>
<div class="randomItem">2</div>
<div class="randomItem">3</div>
<div class="randomItem">4</div>
<div class="randomItem">5</div>
<div class="randomItem">6</div>
<div class="randomItem">7</div>
<div class="randomItem">8</div>
<div class="randomItem">9</div>
<div class="randomItem">10</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I tried running the script you suggested, but it came up saying there was a Syntax error on the line:

const randomInt = (limit) => Math.floor(Math.random() * limit);

Comment: @neilwhitedesign What browser are you running the snippet on?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I'm using both Chrome and Internet Explorer, but the Syntax error is showing up in Dreamweaver

Comment: @neilwhitedesign I'm not familiar with Dreamweaver. Is the application up-to-date? Or are you using an outdated version? I've updated the answer to include a snippet without JavaScript ES5 features.

Comment: Thanks for the additional response.
Using an updated version of Dreamweaver, the syntax error no longer shows.

Should I just be able to copy and paste your code into my .js file?
Because when I do and refresh the html page, all 18 of the "randomItem" divs are now showing and always in the same order, as though the script is having no effect.

Thanks